# Trouble updating a cell in a MySQL DB?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, google-maps

I have a google maps web application for a game where the user will click a google map marker, make a selection in the window that pops up and click submit. It uses AJAX to update the database with information selected by the user. The database is pre-populated with names of the markers and GPS coordinates, which are loaded. The markers are also placed accordingly upon load via XML.

I'm having trouble updating one row in my DB called **quest** with the user selected information when it's submitted. Currently, a user can select a marker and submit a quest, but it won't update the DB at all. I'm unsure on the correct WHERE statement to use. Here's my current SQL statement, I'm trying to update a row called **quest**.

```
mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE markers SET quest= '$questName'  WHERE markerName = '$markerName'");
```

Here's my downloadURL function inside of myMap function

```
downloadUrl("call2.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("markerName");
    //  var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
  var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
  var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
      parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
      parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("longg")));
  var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: point,
    icon: icon.icon,
    shadow: icon.shadow
  });
  bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
}
});
```

This is what happens when the submit button is pressed.

```
if (document.getElementById("questType").value == 
"quest1") { //if quest1 is selected upon submission
alert("quest1");
var markerName;
var questName = "Quest 1";

xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); //Creating the 
XMLHttpRequest object           
xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajax.php?questName=" + questName 
+ "&markerName=" + markerName, true); //Specifying the type of request to the server                    
xmlhttp.send(); //Sending the request to the server
```

Here is my relevant ajax.php.

```
<?php 
include("connect.php");
require("call.php");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . 
mysqli_connect_error();     
} else  {   

} 

$markerName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, 
$_GET['markerName']);
$questName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['questName']);
$lat = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['lat']);
$longg = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['longg']);
mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE markers SET quest= 
'$questName'  WHERE markerName = '$markerName'");
mysqli_close($con);
```

Here is my relevant call file as well.

```
$dom     = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node    = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);
include('connect.php');
$query  = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1"; // Select all the rows in the markers table
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
if (!$result) {
die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
global $dom, $node, $parnode;

    $node    = $dom->createElement("marker");
    $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
    $newnode->setAttribute("markerName", 
    $row['markerName']);
    $newnode->setAttribute("quest", $row['quest']);
    $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
    $newnode->setAttribute("longg", $row['longg']);
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

I don't get any errors, however when I hover over the ajaxphp in the network tab on chrome it looks like it's getting the questName but markerName remains undefined.

Comment: You don't seem to be setting `markerName` anywhere?

Comment: would i just declare var markerName; ?

Comment: You've done that, but you're never assigning a value to it. So `ajax.php` always has `$_GET['markerName']=''`. It's not clear from your code where the value is supposed to come from.

Comment: I have added more of my code, I pasted my downloadUrl function which loads my xml file

Comment: So that looks good, but in your submit code, you have `var markerName; ... xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajax.php?questName=" + questName 
+ "&markerName=" + markerName, true);` and nowhere in the middle do you assign a value to `markerName`. It seems that somewhere you need to assign `markerName` from one of these: `var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");`

Comment: thank you that makes sense, would i need to pass markers as a parameter since its used in a different function i wonder? if i did something like var markerName = markers

Comment: At the moment `markers` is local to the function which downloads the XML file. So you would need a way to save that data somewhere - perhaps you can do it in the marker on the map? I'm not familiar enough with google maps to know the answer to that I'm afraid. I'll add the `googlemaps` tag to your question so you might get some answers from experts in that topic.

Comment: Thank you for the help so far, i'll continue on finding a fix